# PrimeNG: how to call accordion header name & collapse it from angular component.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, accordion

I want to call accordion tab header's name in component.ts to collapse it by some condition. i want to add that function ngOnInit.

I've tried call some method from API documentation from PrimeNG but it's not working.

```
<p-accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
       Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

https://primeng.org/accordion

Comment: Please share you component ts file too. So we can get an idea of what function you try to call and how you are are accessing accordion

Comment: thank you for your comment. I just want to know how we call accordion in component.ts

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the selected tab or toggle the tab dynamically in PrimeNG's p-accordion component, you can follow these steps:

1- Add a template reference #accordion to the p-accordion component in your HTML template:

```
<p-accordion #accordion>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 1">
       Content 1
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 2">
        Content 2
    </p-accordionTab>
    <p-accordionTab header="Header 3">
        Content 3    
    </p-accordionTab>
</p-accordion>
```

2- In your component class, implement the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook:

3- Add `@ViewChild` for  `#accordion` template ref:

```
  @ViewChild('accordion') accordion: Accordion;
```

4- Inside the `ngAfterViewInit()` method, you can evaluate your condition and set the selected property of the desired tab to true. Replace `this.condition` with your actual condition, and `indexOfTab` with the index of the tab you want to select or toggle.

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (this.condition) {
      this.accordion.tabs[indexOfTab].selected = true;
      //OR
      this.accordion.tabs[indexOfTab].toggle(indexOfTab);


    }
  }
```

Comment: For me this does not works, I always get this.accordion equals undefined.

Comment: I've tried it many times and it actually works for me! Mind sharing your code so I can help you figure out the issue? Thanks! @PerezCh